# display string in array using php

Tags: mysql, arrays, charts

I have got a problem. I am trying to display chart with PHP and my chart code is like this.

Database code

```
    $rowval=$sqcat1->qcategory;
    $per=($sqcat1->point_value*100)/($sqcat1->r_count*5);
```

and chart code

```
        $data3['$rowval'] = $per;
        $mc3 = new maxChart($data3);
        $mc3->displayChart('Chart',1,500,600,true);
```

I actually want to pass the value like this

```
$data3['Windows']=80;
$data3['linux']=10;
$data3['Mac']=10;
```

etc extracting the data through the database.

I already try it doing like this

```
$data[$sqcat1->qcategory]= $per;



        $mc3 = new maxChart($data);
        $mc3->displayChart('Chart',1,500,600,true);
```

Its displays chart with percentage only not with the category and percent.

I want to display the category as well as percentage.

somebody please help me.

Comment: @surinder I am using maxChart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
$rowval=$sqcat1->qcategory;
$data["$rowval"]= $per;
$mc3 = new maxChart($data);
$mc3->displayChart('Chart',1,500,600,true);
```

Please note the double quotes $data["$rowval"]

Comment: Its not work. it only pass $per value.Ya i tried to do according to you but its only pass the percent valu.

Comment: can you check if there is any value for "$sqcat1->qcategory" otherwise I can't c any problem in it. I even tried this. $arr = array('Windows','Linux','Mac');
            $data3[$arr[0]] = 55;
            $data3[$arr[1]] = 7;
            $data3[$arr[2]] = 3;
            $mc3 = new maxChart($data3);
            $mc3->displayChart('Demo chart - 4',1,200,150,true); which worked well